Presentation Complex is Homotopy Equivalent to Wedge of Two-Spheres
Let $G$ be a group with presentation $\langle a,b \mid a^3, b^3, (ab)^2\rangle$. Denote the presentation complex of $G$ as $X$. Then the universal cover of $X$, which we denote as $\tilde{X}$, is homotopy equivalent to the wedge of $k$ two-spheres. What is $k$?

To answer this, I first draw the Cayley graph of $G$ which will be the one-skeleton of $\tilde{X}$. This produces a graph which looks like the one-skeleton of the boundary of a cuboctahedron, which is depicted in the "graph" section of the cuboctahedron wiki page (See here). I also copy by illustration of of the Cayley graph below,  where the triangular red arrows denote $b$ edges and the gold V-shaped arrows denote the $a$ edges.
To construct the $\tilde{X}$, I want to stick disks along the closed loops of this Cayley graph. For any triangle in the figure, there are $3$ closed loops, corresponding to starting at the different vertices. So, any triangle produces a shape which looks like a two-sphere with a disk across the middle. We then homotopy the edge of this disk up to a point on the two-sphere, which produces another two-sphere. So, any triangle in the Cayley graph corresponds to the wedge of $3$ two-spheres in $\tilde{X}$.
For any square in the figure, there are two closed loops, corresponding to the two vertices from which $ab$ moves from one side of the square to the opposite vertex. So, any square corresponds to two disks glued along the boundary of the square. This is homotopy equivalent to $1$ two-sphere. So any square in the Cayley graph corresponds to $1$ two-sphere in $\tilde{X}$.
Since there are $8$ triangles, and $6$ squares, the total number of two-spheres we need to glue on to the Cayley graph is $$8(3)+6(1)=24+6=30$$ Hence, I want to assert that $k=30$.
Is my working correct? Or is there a better way to compute $k$? I feel I haven't been very careful about how the triangles and squares connect to one another.
